# Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.lang.Class] SpringMVC + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

i see that its known issue, but solution posted dont resolve my problem. I try to deploy my first hibernate app, and i get following exception:

```
    ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag - Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.lang.Class]: Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.lang.Class]: Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:725)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.person_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(person_jsp.java:334)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.person_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(person_jsp.java:291)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.person_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(person_jsp.java:208)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.person_jsp._jspService(person_jsp.java:135)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1217)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1083)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

these are contents of files we concern:

person.jsp

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/person/add" ></c:url>

<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id"> // <-- this line causes exception
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
```

Person.java - my entity

```
package com.crudvoid.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String country;
  }
```

PersonController.java

```
package com.crudvoid;

import com.crudvoid.model.Person;
import com.crudvoid.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class PersonController {
    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", Person.class);
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());

        return "person";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
        if(person.getId() == 0) {
            this.personService.addPerson(person);
        }
        else {
            this.personService.updatePerson(person);
        }

        return "redirect:/person";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        this.personService.removePerson(id);

        return "redirect:/person";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", this.personService.getPersonById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());

        return "person";
    }
}
```

That's it i think. I will post more if necessary. Im so pissed off, trying to figure out whats wrong all day. Please help!

It's not setter/getter, i use Lombok addon which create (not only) setters and getters during compilation.

Cheers, void

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the line `model.addAttribute("person", Person.class);` in `PersonController`.  Did you perhaps mean `model.addAttribute("person", new Person());` instead?

Comment: That solved my issue... Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, the solution was to replace the line

```
model.addAttribute("person", Person.class);
```

in `listPersons()` with

```
model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
```